# How to convert a string to ASCII

Tags: c#, string, ascii

How do I convert each letter in a string to its ASCII character value?

Comment: Each letter is already it's ASCII character value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For Any String try this:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
foreach( char c in s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToInt32(c));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: what if the string has unicode chars ,what does above code print?

Comment: @Srinivas: See my answer for more details - and an alternative to calling Convert.ToInt32.

Comment: Using an Int32 (4 bytes) to represent an ASCII char requiring 1 byte. Doesn't look like this response should be marked as best response.

Answer (score 31):

.NET stores all strings as a sequence of UTF-16 code units. (This is close enough to "Unicode characters" for most purposes.)

Fortunately for you, Unicode was designed such that ASCII values map to the same number in Unicode, so after you've converted each character to an integer, you can just check whether it's in the ASCII range. Note that you can use an implicit conversion from `char` to `int` - there's no need to call a conversion method:

```
string text = "Here's some text including a \u00ff non-ASCII character";
foreach (char c in text)
{
    int unicode = c;
    Console.WriteLine(unicode < 128 ? "ASCII: {0}" : "Non-ASCII: {0}", unicode);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try Linq:

```
Result = string.Join("", input.ToCharArray().Where(x=> ((int)x) < 127));
```

This will filter out all non ascii characters. Now if you want an equivalent, try the following:

```
Result = string.Join("", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input.ToCharArray())));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString);
```

In the ASCII enconding each char is represented with 1 byte, however in C# the string type uses 2 bytes per char.
This happens because .NET uses UTF-16 to encode the text in a string.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction

Hence, if you want to keep an ASCII "string" in memory, the most efficient way is to use a byte array.
You can always convert it back to string, but remember it will double in size in memory because as soon as it is converted to String it gets converted to UTF-16.

```
string value = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code may be help you:

```
string str = char.ConvertFromUtf32(65)
```

Comment: you should adapt your answer!

Comment: Although it did not answer the original question, it was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your wrong post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method based on Jon Skeet's answer:

```
    public static string ConvertUnicodeStringToAscii(this string text)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            int unicode = c;
            if (unicode < 128)
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToInt32() for conversion. You can have a look at *[How to convert string to ASCII value in C#](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/convert-string-ascii-value-c-t1230725.html)* and *[ASCII values](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/241177-ascii-values)*.

Comment: There's no need to call a method. There's an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using  LINQ-expression.

```
  public static List<int> StringToAscii(string value)
  {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", nameof(value));

        return value.Select(System.Convert.ToInt32).ToList();
  }
```