# Using ASCII equivalent in LINQ

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have a list which want to order by the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code of one field. What is the equivalent of an ASCII method in [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

```
revisions = revisions.OrderBy(x => Ascii(x.SubRevision) % 90).ToList();
```

Method `Ascii` doesn't exist in LINQ. How I can use it?

Comment: if `SubRevision` is char you can just add (int) -> `(int)x.SubRevision` otherwise look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348844/how-to-convert-string-to-ascii

Comment: What type of x.SubRevision? And why you have added %90 there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with LINQ really. If `x.SubRevision` is a char property you can simply cast it into an integer to get the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value:

```
revisions = revisions.OrderBy(x => ((int)x.SubRevision) % 90).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is, though. The function you need to use is `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.Ascii(x.Subrevision)`. This takes the leftmost character in x.Subrevision and gives the ASCII code for it.

However, this method can only be used in a [LINQ to Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework#LINQ_to_Entities) query, not [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29).

Like the others have answered, characters in C# can be casted to int for the same effect. So if x.Subrevision is a character you can simply cast it to int, if it's a string, you can cast the leftmost character to string, like this:

```
(int)x.Subrevision[0]
```