# Hex string to ASCII conversion working but not for all characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, hex, ascii

I am trying to convert Hex string to ASCII in c# using visual studio community 2017. 
My Hex string looks like below

```
070196000008220031CE4745542073776964FD48
```

when i convert it into ASCII it looks like below

[image]

my confusion is why it is showing ASCII "\a" for hex "07"?? it should be . ASCII value for hex "01" should be  but it showing "\u0001". It is same for ASCII control characters and extended ASCII charecters.

Can someone explain please! Am i missing anything and how to get like that.

The code i am using to convert hextoascii

```
    public string ConvertHextoASCII(String hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            string ascii = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                String hs = string.Empty;

                hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                int decval = System.Convert.ToInt32(hs, 16);
                char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
                ascii += character;
            }
            return ascii;
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        return string.Empty;
     }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Convert string of integers to ASCII chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53791357/7444103). But, what kind of results are you expecting from that string content? Most of its content can't be translated to a printable ASCII char.

Comment: Also, your data is not ASCII but that's okay because .NET doesn't use ASCII. It uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. There is a problem, though, in that you are taking two hex digits at a time and interpreting them as an UTF-16 code unit (which requires two bytes/four digits in an agreed-upon order). Consider the Encoding classes to convert bytes to String.

Comment: this sequence of ASCII characters will be sent to hardware as a command to get response. when i send this sequence"<BEL><SOH>-<NUL><NUL><BS>"<NUL>É7GET swid ýH". I am getting response from hardware in terminal. I am trying to do the same with C# program.

Comment: This is an information that surely needs to be specified in the question. In **Bold**. Read what Tom Blodget wrote, what you need to change is all there.

Answer (score 1):

Certain characters can be escaped in a way besides `\u1234` if they're in a string literal. The `\a` corresponds to the "Bell (alert)" character - Unicode (and ASCII) code point 7 (0x0007). The debugger appears to prefer these alternate escapes over the `\u1234` format when possible. [Here's the full list of escape sequences in C# string literals.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#character-literals)